# Symfony2 Intl Exception

Tags: php, symfony, symfony-2.3

i deployed a symfony application on centos server but i am getting a error

```
 [Symfony\Component\Intl\Exception\RuntimeException]                                                                                 
 Could not load the resource bundle  "/vendor/symfony/icu/Symfony/Component/Icu/Resources/data/curr/en_IN.res".
```

I am not able to figure out the issue.

Comment: Does all your vendors are updated [or installed] ?

Answer (score 0):

Do you have any warning or failure in the result of `php app/check.php`? I think you don't have php(5)-intl on your system.

[The Intl Component](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/intl.html)